# .net core HTTPS requests returns 502 bad gateway while Postman returns 200 OK

Tags: c#, post, https, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

What's wrong with this code snippet in C#.NET core 3:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
            {
                Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                Host = "api.omniexplorer.info",
                Path = "v1/transaction/address",
            };

            var req = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "addr", "1FoWyxwPXuj4C6abqwhjDWdz6D4PZgYRjA" }
            };

            using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req)));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running this with a breakpoint at the line `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`, I always get 502 response. However, if running this in Postman or in curl, I got back a valid result.

Example in curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "addr=1EXoDusjGwvnjZUyKkxZ4UHEf77z6A5S4P" "https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/transaction/address"
```

Many thanks for helping a newbie out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so instead of `StringContent` use `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(req);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, content);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That works. However, I have to remove the line `content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` since it yields an exception: `Cannot add value because header 'Content-Type' does not support multiple values.` Should we call something like `content.Headers.Clear()` first?

Comment: @user_0_found I've updated answer - there is a `ContentType` property of `FormUrlEncodedContent` which should be used instead of `Headers.Add`. Hopefully that works for you now