# PostAsync API giving Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, api

I am invoking a third party POST API from my own API (again POST METHOD). The third party API is having a security key, and  it is working fine on the POSTMAN tool. However, when  I tries to invoke through code, I am getting error, 'Bad Gateway'. Following is the code which I tried.

```
 public static async Task<string> GetDetailsfromThirdParty(string kszstrng)
    {
       
        string contentstring = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {               

            string baseURL = "https://abcde.kz.in/b2/vhsearch-all";              
            string prms = kszstrng;// input parameters to API, in JSON Format- this is JSON String.
            
            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    byte[] messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prms);
                    var content = new ByteArrayContent(messageBytes);
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");   
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseURL, content).ConfigureAwait(false);                       
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    contentstring = result;                        

                  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                string msg = ex.Message.ToString();
                
                }
            return contentstring;
        }
    }
```

I am getting error on this line:

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseURL, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

While trying to execute I am getting the below error:
[image: Bad Gateway]

Not able to find out what's the issue? There is no network / Fireawall blockage. I have cross-verified with Systems Team as well.

Please suggest any issue with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. While forming the object to JSON String,  there was an opening and closing  angle brackets ([,]). Even though this is coming automatically while converting to JSON string, this was not accepted string at the vendor end. So I removed it and works perfectly. Thanks every one for the support.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i recommend you to not declare the HttpClient in a using statement since this can cause a socket exhaustion (because the connections will stay open).

(see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) for details)

Go for a static HttpClient (or use the IHttpClientFactory if you're project is .net Core).

I can't test your code since I'm not able to access this api.

But give it a try using a cleaner approach:

```
// static HttpClient
private static readonly HttpClient _HttpClient = new HttpClient();

// Can be used to set the baseUrl of the HttpClient from outside
public static void SetBaseUrl(Uri baseUrl)
{
    _HttpClient.BaseAddress = baseUrl;
}

public static async Task<string> GetDetailsfromThirdParty(string kszstrng)
{
    string contentstring = string.Empty;

    string baseURL = "https://abcde.kz.in/b2/vhsearch-all";
    string prms = kszstrng; // input parameters to API, in JSON Format- this is JSON String.

    try
    {
        // Be aware of which headers you wanna clean if using the static HttpClient
        _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");
        _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prms);
        var content = new ByteArrayContent(messageBytes);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await _HttpClient.PostAsync(baseURL, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            contentstring = result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // your exception handling
    }

    return contentstring;
}
```

Comment: Thank you john. But I am sorry that I am getting Bad Gateway error still. I am using .Net Framework 4.8, Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236222/net-core-https-requests-returns-502-bad-gateway-while-postman-returns-200-ok) and by not having further information about the error, I would make sure the content type is correct in the next step.